# How to use NextJS Image Component to display images receiving through props?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-props, nextjs-image, react-image

Simply I wanna display images that I'm receiving through `props`

```
import Image from "next/image";
import classes from "./book-item.module.css";

export default function FoodItems(props) {
    return (
        <li className={classes.product__item}>
            <Image
                src={props.imageUrl}
                alt={props.title}
                className={classes.image}
                width={100}
                height={100}
            />
            <h3>{props.title}</h3>
            <p>{props.price}</p>
        </li>
    );
}
```

I'm getting this error from the above code:-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error clearly states what you are missing i.e you need to add allowed domains for images to load from in `next.config.js` file.

- Open `next.config.js` file
- Add `images: { domains: ["itbook.store"], },` add all the domains from where you load images in this array

Comment: these are the image which are coming from API, how can I create array of it here?

Comment: You just need to add domain name.. not the whole url.. e.g :  if all images are coming from `itbook.store` domain then the above snippet in answer is enough.

Comment: I've tried that but still getting the same error, please check my next.config.js file here:- https://github.com/mohitdevelops/book-store-app/blob/main/next.config.js

Comment: make sure you stop the nextjs server and restart it, since editing next config files requires a server restart